# How can I substitute the values of 2 variables in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I read the value of the variable I want to change (a) and then I read the new value of it (b).

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
read b
sed 's/$a/$b/' file.txt
```

file.txt contains only numbers

This is the code and it doesn't make the substitute.

Comment: It should work unless `$a` or `$b` contains `/` character. Do you get an error?

Comment: What are the values you set for `a` and `b`?  Does the string you assign to `b` appear in the file?  Do you get an error message?  There are many details missing here.

Comment: Please clarify. You want to change `b` into `a`? Not the other way around?

Comment: You have the variables in the wrong order. It's `s/old/new/`.

Comment: please update the question with the contents of a sample `file`, the values of `a` and `b` (eg, add `declare -p a b` before the `sed` call), and the expected change to `file`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course not. You're using single quotes, so the parameters are never expanded. (I see from the edit history you just replaced the double quotes with single quotes; why?)

Comment: We still don't know what values you are supply for `a` and `b`, nor what is in `file.txt`, so it's impossible to say why your script (with double quotes) isn't working as expected.

Comment: As chepner said, variable references don't work inside single-quotes. See ["Difference between single and double quotes in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quote, instead of single quote: single quote prevents variable expansion:

```sh
sed "s/$a/$b/" file.txt
```